# dplyr and tail to change last value in a group_by in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tail

while using dplyr i'm having trouble changing the last value my data frame.  i want to group by user and tag and change the Time to 0 for the last value / row in the group.

```
     user_id     tag   Time
1  268096674       1    3
2  268096674       1    10
3  268096674       1    1
4  268096674       1    0
5  268096674       1    9999
6  268096674       2    0
7  268096674       2    9
8  268096674       2    500
9  268096674       3    0
10 268096674       3    1
...
```

Desired output:

```
     user_id     tag   Time
1  268096674       1    3
2  268096674       1    10
3  268096674       1    1
4  268096674       1    0
5  268096674       1    0
6  268096674       2    0
7  268096674       2    9
8  268096674       2    0
9  268096674       3    0
10 268096674       3    1
...
```

I've tried to do something like this, among others and can't figure it out:

```
df %>%
  group_by(user_id,tag) %>%
  mutate(tail(Time) <- 0)
```

I tried adding a row number as well, but couldn't quite put it all together.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to offer an alternative approach which will avoid copying the whole column (what both `Time[-n()]` and `replace` do) and allow modifying in place

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[.N], by = .(user_id, tag)]$V1 # finding the last incidences per group
df[indx, Time := 0L] # modifying in place
df
#       user_id tag Time
#  1: 268096674   1    3
#  2: 268096674   1   10
#  3: 268096674   1    1
#  4: 268096674   1    0
#  5: 268096674   1    0
#  6: 268096674   2    0
#  7: 268096674   2    9
#  8: 268096674   2    0
#  9: 268096674   3    0
# 10: 268096674   3    0
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's an option:

```
df %>%
  group_by(user_id, tag) %>%
  mutate(Time = c(Time[-n()], 0))
#Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
#Groups: user_id, tag
#
#     user_id tag Time
#1  268096674   1    3
#2  268096674   1   10
#3  268096674   1    1
#4  268096674   1    0
#5  268096674   1    0
#6  268096674   2    0
#7  268096674   2    9
#8  268096674   2    0
#9  268096674   3    0
#10 268096674   3    0
```

What I did here is: create a vector of the existing column "Time" with all elements except for the last one in the group, which has the index `n()` and add to that vector a `0` as last element using `c()` for concatenation.

Note that in my output the Time value in row 10 is also changed to 0 because it is considered the last entry of the group.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar: `mutate(Time = replace(Time, n(), 0)`.

Comment: Another, less elegant, option could be: `mutate(Time = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 0, Time))`