# Replacing the last value within groups with different values

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

My question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881518/dplyr-and-tail-to-change-last-value-in-a-group-by-in-r), but the difference is instead of replacing the last value within each group/id with all 0's, different values are used to replace the last value within each group/id.

Here is an example (I borrowed it from the above link):

```
          id  Time
1         1    3
2         1    10
3         1    1
4         1    0
5         1    9999
6         2    0
7         2    9
8         2    500
9         3    0
10        3    1
```

In the above link, the last value within each group/id was replaced by a zero, using something like:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Time = c(Time[-n()], 0))
```

And the output was

```
          id  Time
1         1    3
2         1    10
3         1    1
4         1    0
5         1    0
6         2    0
7         2    9
8         2    0
9         3    0
10        3    0
```

In my case, I would like the last value within each group/id to be replaced by a different value. Originally, the last value within each group/id was `9999`, `500`, and `1`. Now I would like: `9999` is replaced by `5`, `500` is replaced by `12`, and `1` is replaced by `92`. The desired output is:

```
          id  Time
1         1    3
2         1    10
3         1    1
4         1    0
5         1    5
6         2    0
7         2    9
8         2    12
9         3    0
10        3    92
```

I tried this one:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Time = replace(Time, n(), c(5,12,92))),
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide sample data and code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You can't insert several values into a single one. You should provide a reproducible example and your desired output as pointed out by @scoa

Comment: @goren9 Are you Jason? If not, why have you rewritten his question?

Comment: Anyway, voting to reopen now that the question makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank.

Comment: When you say 'it did not work', what output did you get instead?

Comment: The last value within each group was replaced by "5", the 1st value in c(5,12,92). And I got warning messages: 1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length ...

Answer (score 3):

This could be solved using almost identical solution as I posted in the linked question. e.g., just replace `0L` with the desired values

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[.N], by = id]$V1
df[indx, Time := c(5L, 12L, 92L)]
df
#     id Time
#  1:  1    3
#  2:  1   10
#  3:  1    1
#  4:  1    0
#  5:  1    5
#  6:  2    0
#  7:  2    9
#  8:  2   12
#  9:  3    0
# 10:  3   92
```

---

So to add some explanations:

1. `.I` is identical to `row_number()` or `1:n()` in `dplyr` for an *ungrouped* data, e.g. `1:nrow(df)` in base R
2. `.N` is like `n()` in `dplyr`, e.g., the size of a certain group (or the whole data set). So basically when I run `.I[.N]` by group, I'm retrieving the *global* index of the last row *of each group*
3. The next step is just use this index as a row index within `df` while assigning the desired values to `Time` *by reference* using the `:=` operator.

---

**Edit**

Per OPs request, here's a possible `dplyr` solution. Your original solution doesn't work because you are working per group and thus you were trying to pass all three values to each group.

The only way I can think of is to first calculate group sizes, then ungroup and then mutate on the cumulative sum of these locations, something among these lines

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indx = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Time = replace(Time, cumsum(unique(indx)), c(5, 12, 92))) %>%
  select(-indx)

# Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
# 
#    id Time
# 1   1    3
# 2   1   10
# 3   1    1
# 4   1    0
# 5   1    5
# 6   2    0
# 7   2    9
# 8   2   12
# 9   3    0
# 10  3   92
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. I use "data.table" a lot as well, but just out of curiosity: how to do it using something like "mutate(Time = replace(Time, n(), c(5,12,92)))"?

Comment: Thank you very much, David.

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `data.table` would be to create another *data.table* which contains the values to be replaced with for a given `id`, and then *join and update by reference* (simultaneously).

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+ (for 'on = ' feature)
replace = data.table(id = 1:3, val = c(5L, 12L, 9L)) # from @David
setDT(df)[replace, Time := val, on = "id", mult = "last"]

#     id Time
#  1:  1    3
#  2:  1   10
#  3:  1    1
#  4:  1    0
#  5:  1    5
#  6:  2    0
#  7:  2    9
#  8:  2   12
#  9:  3    0
# 10:  3    9
```

> In `data.table`, *joins* are considered as an extension of *subsets*. It's natural to think of doing whatever operation we do on *subsets* also on *joins*. Both operations *do something on some rows*.

For each `replace$id`, we find the last matching row (`mult = "last"`) in `df$id`, **and** *update* that row with the corresponding `val`.

Installation instructions for `v1.9.5` [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). Hope this helps.